# Html slider not responsive

Tags: html, css, slider, responsive

Can you do it slider in img responsive
Slider:https://yadi.sk/d/UH8I2FyOyjzPF

Comment: welcome to SO  community. but this is not a descriptive question. please try try to explain deeper and stick to the standards. follow the link to know how an SO question should be http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just asked if you could make this slider mobile compatible

Comment: atleast show us a demo

Comment: Files have yandex link 
It is not its demo: http://www.pastek.com.tr/FourBoxes/index2.html

Comment: it is responsive. the only problem is the image which u are using doesn't comes responsive

Comment: I did not apply it, but I could not max-width:100% height:auto;

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://getbootstrap.com/ for creating a responsive slider

slider: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

and you can use responsive image always through bootstrap with http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive